# Is there documentation for Mozilla marionette protocol commands?

Tags: web-api-testing, firefox-marionette

**Marionette** is a protocol for remotely controlling Mozilla browsers. Chromium has the **DevTools** protocol for the same purpose, and it is [documented here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot).

Marionette has some [sketchy documentation here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Protocol.html), but is there a proper list of available commands and parameters? Can it be extracted from Mozilla sources somehow? (Like Chromium has [PDL](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/tree/master/pdl).)

By commands I mean the likes of `[0,1,"WebDriver:Navigate",{"url":"http://awe.lv"}]}]`
, "WebDriver:GetTitle", `[0,2,"WebDriver:ExecuteAsyncScript",{"script":"alert('Hello!')"}]`
, "WebDriver:GetWindowHandle", "WebDriver:GetWindowRect", "WebDriver:TakeScreenshot" and "WebDriver:GetPageSource". In particular, I want to observe the network traffic like with the DevTools' method `Network.enable`.

Are there any other prefixes (than "WebDriver:") available? Can we use the [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) via Marionette?

Answer (score 4):

Played around a bit with `geckodriver` and `Wireshark`:

Start Firefox with `--marionette`; personally I like to add `--headless --no-remote --profile $(mktemp -d)`, but this is up to you! Opens FireFox listening on port 2828 (there is a way to change this, but I'm not 100% sure how).

The Marionette protocol is as follows:

- each message is a length-prefixed json message without newline (so for instance, when you connect `telnet localhost 2828`, you're greeted by `50:{"applicationType":"gecko","marionetteProtocol":3}`, the `50` meaning the json is 50 bytes long.
- each message (except for the first one) are a json array of 4 items:

  - `[0, messageId, command, body]` for a request, where `messageId` is an int, `command` a string and `body` an object. Example (with length prefix) `31:[0,1,"WebDriver:NewSession",{}]`
  - `[1, messageId, error, reply]` for a reply. Here `messageId` is the id the reply was to, and either `error` or `result` is null (depending on whether there is an error). E.g. `697:[1,1,null,{"sessionId":"d9dbe...", ..., "proxy":{}}}]`
- A full list of all commands can be found in the [Marionette source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/remote/marionette/driver.sys.mjs#3403), and it seems to me that all functions there are pretty well documented. For one thing, it seems that they expose all webdriver functions under `WebDriver:*`.

---

Update: it seems that https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1421766 is also struggling with finding the right marionette port/setting the port. The way I now do it:

```bash
TEMPD="$(mktemp -d)"
echo 'user_pref("marionette.port", 0);' >  "${TEMPD}"/prefs.js
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --marionette --headless --no-remote --profile "${TEMPD}" &
PID=$!
MARIONETTE_PORT=""
while [ -z "$MARIONETTE_PORT" ]; do
  sleep 1
  MARIONETTE_PORT=$(lsof -a -p $PID -s TCP:LISTEN -i4 -nP | grep -oE ':\d+ \(LISTEN\)' | grep -oE '\d+')
done
echo "Marionette started on port $MARIONETTE_PORT"
fg
```

(Giving port 0 makes Firefox choose a random empty port. The command works for MacOS; will probably need some tweaking on Linux (I think the arguments to `lsof` are slightly different; also Linux `grep` has lookbehind/lookahead, so you could replace the double `grep` by a single one).

---

UPDATE 2

Since Firefox will write the Marionette port it uses to `"${TEMPD}"/prefs.js`, one does not even need to do "fancy" things with `lsof`; rather just check that file:

```bash
TEMPD="$(mktemp -d)"
echo 'user_pref("marionette.port", 0);' >  "${TEMPD}"/prefs.js
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --marionette --headless --no-remote --profile "${TEMPD}" &
MARIONETTE_PORT=""
while [ -z "$MARIONETTE_PORT" ]; do
  sleep 1
  MARIONETTE_PORT=$(cat "${TEMPD}"/prefs.js | grep 'user_pref("marionette.port"' | grep -oE '[1-9][0-9]*')
done
echo "Marionette started on port $MARIONETTE_PORT"
fg
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found a list of commands at [Geckodriver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Commands), pointed to by [source](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/geckodriver/README.md).
But what a meager set of commands, and the documentation is also not complete! I hoped one could use all the [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) via Marionette.

Comment: Webdriver is meant to allow browser automation by providing APIs that allows one to mimic human behavior like navigate to page, move mouse, input text and click on elements and a way to check page's reactions to that actions. That's why only selector querying from DOM API is implement, the rest of APIs can be accessed by evaluating arbitrary JS on the page which is supported by geckodriver.

Comment: Webdriver target use is web page test automation, not an alternative way to navigate on the web.