# Firefox Marionette Commands Without Selenium And Geckodriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I want to use Firefox's marionette interface directly over TCP without using any geckodriver or selenium packages. But I failed finding any documentation about marionette commands list. There is only a brief documentation about how the protocol works in general **[here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Protocol.html)**. But what I need is a complete documentation of all possible commands with interfaces and data models and such.

Where can I find it?

Comment: You didn't say which programming language you want to use, but there's a [Python client](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/python/marionette_driver.html)

Comment: @ou_ryperd that one is still just another client using marionette port to communicate with firefox. I want to build my own client and communicate with marionette port directly over TCP connection.

Comment: oh I see. Contact the authors. https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/index.html#communication

Answer (score 1):

I fear you wont find the information that you want the way you want.

The best way I found to develop my own library in golang (https://github.com/njasm/marionette_client) was/is to read the source code. Nothing beats that, right? :)

Marionette commands are mostly WebDriver ones, so by reading the source code of the marionette driver server that ships with Firefox you can find all the commands that are currently implemented.

You can browse Firefox source in searchfox.

More precisely here is the direct link to Marionette driver commands for the current Firefox release: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/marionette/driver.js#3896

Comment: [New link to the source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/remote/marionette/driver.js) (don't want to edit, since I'm not sure it's the same code):  . Also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68747295/1207489) @Noldor